# Permissions in BroadcastReceiver on Android 6

Tags: java, android

whats wrong with runtime permissions in broadcast receivers on Android 6?
 I have call log broadcast receiver which I defined in AndroidManifest and 
it starts when I launch this app. MainActivity contain onCreate method, in this method
I try to check permissions and call permission dialog, but it's too late, because
broadcast receiver is starting before onCreate method and then I don't have permission
to read call log.

Comment: "whats wrong with runtime permissions in broadcast receivers on Android 6?" -- nothing. You'll just have to learn how asynchronous code works.

Comment: just request permission in start of your `Activity` for future broadcasts. this mechanism exists not only to complicate work for programmers, but also for informing users about data-sensitive usage by app (easy to forbide unneceassary/unwanted/suspicious access). if Android team made your permission "requestable" ony on runtime then you have to live with that. [DOC HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: ok, I'm doing it, but I'm not sure that requesting permissions in onCreate method is the best solution for prepare broadcast receiver. I should ask for all permissions at one time, but I'm don't know why only part of all permissions requests is called.